# Continuity of $f(x) = x^2$ extended by $f(0)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I want to prove that the function $\;f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 & x \neq 0 \\ 1 & x = 0 \end{cases}$$

has a discontinuity at $x=0$ using exclusively the $(\epsilon, \delta)$-definition of continuity.

Using the $(\epsilon, \delta)$-definition of continuity at $x_0=0$ and letting $0\lt\epsilon \lt 1$ implies that $\lvert f(x)-f(x_0)\rvert=\lvert x^2-1 \rvert\lt\epsilon$ can be rewritten $$\sqrt{1-\epsilon}\lt x \lt\sqrt{1+\epsilon} $$ So for any choice of $\delta \gt 0$ , the intervals $(0, \delta)$ and $(0, \sqrt{1-\epsilon})$ have some points in common. This implies that for all $x \in (0, \delta) \cap (0, \sqrt{1-\epsilon})$ , $\lvert x \rvert \lt \delta$ does not imply that $\lvert x^2-1 \rvert \lt\epsilon$. Thus, no $\delta$ exists such that $$\lvert x-x_0\rvert = \lvert x \rvert \lt \delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(x) - f(x_0)\rvert=\lvert x^2-1\rvert\lt\epsilon$$
Therefore, the function has a discontinuity at $x=0$. Is my process here correct and rigorous?

Comment: What is $\epsilon$? You just say that it's betwen 0 and 1. For proofs like these, defining a specific $\epsilon$ is usually better. For instance, let $\epsilon=1/2$.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is just a positive real number less than 1

Comment: As I said, typically when proving discontinuity, a specific $\epsilon$ is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't just say $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^2 = 0 \not = 1$, hence $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)  \not = f(0)$?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, Did!

Comment: Echoing @JoshuaGray, and using the theorem or sometimes taken as a definition of continuity makes the problem trivial, or even a question such as why $1 \neq 2.$

Comment: @JoshuaGray If the problem _requires_ the use of epsilon-delta, you should say so in the question. The mere fact that you mentioned epsilon-delta in your attempted solution does not tell us it was required; how would we know it is not merely a choice you made?

Comment: @JoshuaGray: Yes, in this sense, there is a loophole in your question. But, as you are a beginner here, you are innocent! I would say just pay a little more attention to formulate a question hereafter :)

Comment: @Chou Do we really need this kind of feelgood atmosphere?

Comment: @JoshuaGray Sorry but I am not the author of this answer.

Comment: @Did: Indeed, I was not trying to make a feel-good atmosphere. I was trying to attenuate a not-in-others's-shoes atmosphere. To me, being professional does not imply being not-in-others's-shoes.

Comment: @Arch This problem requires using the $(\epsilon, \delta)$-definition of continuity exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for my gross error in the previous version.

Let $\varepsilon := \frac{1}{3}$. Then we have $|x^{2} - 1| \geq \frac{1}{3}$ for $|x| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$

Comment: No, $|x^2-1|<\delta^2+1$ and $|x^2-1|<1$ are **not** a contradiction.

Comment: You want to justify $|x^2-1| \geq 1/2$ for $x$ close enough to $0$.

Comment: @Did: You may now check the revision if you would like to.

Comment: The revision is mathematically correct, but I am not sure it is understandable by somebody unable to write a solution by themselves (replacing $\varepsilon$ by $\frac23$, if one insists on using the condition that $|x|\lt\frac1{\sqrt3}$, would be a start).